# Wcf Data Service Reflection Provider complains of unrelated types

Tags: wcf-data-services

I have two services, Customer service and Product service. They are independent and each have their own *Entity Types*. They work ok, when I split them to two different project. However, when they are inside the same project, when I try to navigate to each service url I get a error similar to the following.

`The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Type 'Common.Model.Product' has property 'Category' of entity type. Either this property has no corresponding entity set in the data context or one of its inherited types has a corresponding entity set. Specify IgnoreProperties attribute on the entity type for this property or use a property type that has a corresponding entity set in the data context.'`

In case of this error, I'm tryiing to naviagate Customer Service URL but it complains about a Product Service entity type that is never used or referenced inside Customer Service. Similarily, when I try to Navigate Product Service URL I get this error:

`The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The property 'Customers' on type 'Common.Model.Branch' is not a valid property. Properties whose types are collection of primitives or complex types are not supported.'`

Again, the error is about EntityType that is used in Product Service and is never used or referenced in the Customer Service.

I'd like to repeat that if I split these services and their Entity Types in separate projects, both services run fine.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the Entity Types for both services were derived from the same base class:

```
[DataServiceKeyAttribute("Id")]
public class BaseEntity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #pragma warning disable 67        // Required by the interface
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #pragma warning restore 67

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

For whatever reason (I still not quite understand why) this made the reflection provider walk all the derived classes for each service. When I removed this dependency the services started working.